# "Elements of Programming" real world examples?

Tags: c++

I'm eager to learn about Stepanov's approach to programming described in the book [Elements of Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032163537X). Does anyone here have experience with these methods, or can point me to some online resource where this topic matter is discussed?

I've seen the Adobe's Google Tech Talk on [A Possible future of software development](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4moyKUHApq4).

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a summary of what the methods are, so we have an idea of what you're trying to get out of this question. Also, sounds like this should be a wiki question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was a proofreader for the book, and my feedback to Alex greatly influenced the style of presentation.  I am happy to call myself one of his disciples.  I find the material fascinating, and it has totally changed the way I write code, even Java code.

Some of Alex's "methods" are radical despite the vague wording I am providing:

- Progamming is about two things: algorithms and data structures.
- Think very hard about every line of code you write.
- Understand the structure of the problem you are trying to solve.
- Good code is often rewritten to be better.
- The goal is to write code that is both as general and as fast as possible.
- Naming things correctly is very important.
- Often the core of an algorithm is already a well-understood idea.
- If your function computes something interesting, return it.

How does that turn into source code?  My posts on StackOverflow were done after this improvement in my understanding, so you can read those if you want.  Otherwise, I'm not sure how to answer your question to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of video, Sean Parent mentions http://opensource.adobe.com/

You can check out [Adobe STLab](http://stlab.adobe.com/)

(BTW, I've ordered *Elements of Programming* and I'll receive it tomorrow ;-)

Comment: I hope to receive it soon as well :)

Answer (score 1):

It is good to see Stepanov's talk given at StanfordUniversity.  Is related to his book Elements of Programming. hhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ih9gpJga4Vc He gives his view how programming and mathematics are related.

I find it extremely interesting that Sean Parent (from Adobe Photoshop team) in 2007 has stated that: Photoshop has 3 millions LOC and by using STL (Standard Template Library) methodology it could be rewritten in only 30 kLOC, 100 times less - compression of magnitude 2! http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=4moyKUHApq4#t=2333

I find it fascinating, that STL port (or should it be called rewrite or perhaps refactoring) enables such high, upto 2 orders of magnitude compression of source code of huge applications like MSWord or Adobe Photoshop.

Here is an Interview with Alexander Stepanov http://www.stlport.org/resources/StepanovUSA.html

Comment: Standard Template Library Programmer's Guide http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ gives a valid reference.

Comment: To see Sean Parent's opinions about using the STL to reduce code size, check out: http://sean-parent.stlab.cc/papers-and-presentations#title-c-seasoning . He also gives a version of it In lecture 5 of Alex Stepanov's Programming Conversations series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzNtM038JuI&index=9&list=PLHxtyCq_WDLXFAEA-lYoRNQIezL_vaSX-